# How do I get a code point literal in utf8

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++17

I just recently realized, the `u8` character prefix for C++17 is not meant for *all* utf8 code points, just for the ASCII part.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal)

> UTF-8 character literal, e.g. `u8'a'`. Such literal has type `char` and the value equal to ISO 10646 code point value of c-char, provided that the code point value is representable with a single UTF-8 code unit. If c-char is not in Basic Latin or C0 Controls Unicode block, the program is ill-formed.

```
auto hello = u8'嗨';     // ill-formed
auto world = u8"世";     // not a character
auto what = 0xE7958C;    // almost human-readable
auto wrong = u8"錯"[0];  // not even correct
```

How do I get a code point literal in utf8 succinctly?

EDIT: For the people wondering how a utf8 code point may be stored, a way I find reasonable is like [the way Golang does it](https://blog.golang.org/strings). The basic idea is to store a single code point in a 32-bit type when only a single code point is required.

EDIT2: From the arguments put out by the helpful comments, there is no reason to have encoded utf8 stay in a 32-bit type all along. Either have it decoded, which would be utf32 and have the prefix `U`, or have it encoded in a string, with the prefix `u8`.

Comment: Did you notice [SO: What is the point of the UTF-8 character literals proposed for C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31970111/7478597)?

Comment: @Scheff Yes. But it simply says `u8` is a way to specify the character must be ASCII. It didn't say how do I get a utf8 code point literal

Comment: @Scheff I do see some value in maintaining the same type for strings and characters for the same prefix, but I don't see how it makes sense for there to be no way to specify a single code point.

Comment: Since a code point can have 1 to 4 code units in utf8, I think the only way to represent it in C++ is to use arrays. So, just use `u8"字"`.

Comment: @cpplearner In Go, a single code point is stored in a 32-bit type, which I personally find to be reasonable.

Comment: @passer that isn't utf8.  That is utf32.  The 8 in u8 stands for utf8.

Comment: @Yakk No, that is utf8. The 32-bit type is to ensure any code point can be stored in there as cpplearner said. For instance, if you had a iterator over a utf8 string, the result of a dereference is likely going to be the 32-bit type. The alternative is to store a range in the result type, which sounds pretty dumb

Comment: Following the links in the answer of the above link I understand it like: `u8` grants (by compile check) that a UTF-8 encoding of the resp. code point fits into 1 byte. If you need UTF-8 sequences for other code points... Hmm... encode with `U` prefix, then convert it to character sequence (e.g. by a function) as usual? I believe I got why you asked...

Comment: @passerby "Each 32-bit value in UTF-32 represents one Unicode code point and is exactly equal to that code point's numerical value."  The code point and the utf-32 representation of a character are equal.  When you encode unicode as 32 bit .. you are converting to utf-32.

Comment: @PasserBy UTF-8 splits and encodes (there are some control bits) the "32-bit" codepoint into one or more bytes. Stuffing the codepoint directly into an `uint32` *is* UTF32.

Comment: @Quentin Their representation is different. If we take the third word in the example, `0xE7958C` in utf8 represents `0x4C750000` in utf32. Both is the same word `界`

Comment: @Yakk You pointed out the difference: the value in utf32 is the code point's numerical value, but the value of multiple bytes of utf8, when interpreted as a number, is not.

Comment: @PasserBy yes. And for what I skimmed Golang gives you access to the codepoint (aka UTF-32), not its UTF-8 representation -- what use would that be?

Comment: C++ says nothing about ASCII. Strings and character types in C++ don't store code points, they store code units. Code points are mathematical integers (numbers assigned to Unicode characters). Code units are machine integers of a specific size (e.g. 8, 16 or 32 bits).

Comment: @Quentin Oh yeah... then I messed up big time

Comment: @PasserBy to be fait the doc you linked looks really unclear to me. The code snippet, though, prints codepoints from uint32's without a conversion, so I think I got it right.

Comment: @user2079303: No. It says that Go source code is utf8. But the actual runtime value that is produced by the literal is the Unicode code point which that utf8 literal represents. And the type of the literal is rune, which is not of variable size, but is an [alias of int32](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I seem to have misunderstood. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a codepoint, then you should use `char32_t` and `U` for the prefix:

```
auto hello = U'嗨';
```

UTF-8 stores codepoints as a sequence of 8-bit code units. A `char` in C++ is a code unit, and therefore it cannot store an entire Unicode codepoint. The `u8` prefix on character literals doesn't compile if you provide a codepoint that requires multiple code units to store, since a character literal only yields a single `char`.

If you want a single Unicode codepoint, encoded in UTF8, then what you want is a *string literal*, not a character literal:

```
auto hello = u8"嗨";
```

---

> a way I find reasonable is like the way Golang does it.

Well, you're not using Go, are you?

In C++, if you ask for a character literal, then you mean a single object of that size's type. A `u8` literal will *always* be a `char`. Its type will not vary based on what is in the literal. You asked for a character literal, you get a character literal.

From the website you linked to, it is clear that Go doesn't actually have the concept of a UTF-8 character literal at all. It simply has character literals, *all of which* are 32-bit values. In effect, all character literals in Go behave like `U''`.

Comment: Unless I'm sorely mistaken, `U` is for UTF32 is it not?

Comment: @PasserBy: I'm not really sure what that matters. You either want a Unicode codepoint value or you want a UTF-8 *string* (aka: a sequence of multiple code units). So, which do you want?

Comment: I'd have to convert to and from utf8 and utf32, which have different representations. When keeping the encoding in utf8 and storing it in 32-bit types, I can ignore the leading empty bytes and append to a string _without_ conversions.

Comment: @PasserBy: Or you could just append the UTF-8 string to the other string directly. There's no specific need to store an array of 4 characters in a 32-bit integer. Also, Go doesn't do what you're trying to do either. Or at least, if it does, it's not done on the page you showed. A rune literal is always its codepoint value, not the UTF-8 encoding of it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a character literal is exactly one character object. *character object* in C++ terminology corresponds to *code unit* in Unicode. Some code points of UTF-8 require more than one code unit. Therefore not all UTF-8 code points can be representable by a single character object. The code points that are representable, are the Basic Latin and C0 Control blocks.

To represent any UTF-8 code point, you need an array of code units i.e. a string. There is an analogous prefix for string literals: `u8"☺"`.

Comment: "character object in C++ terminology corresponds to code unit in Unicode": It would seem reasonable that a C++ implementation would choose `char` to correspond to one of Unicode's encoding's code unit sizes but since there are many different ones (7, 8, 16, or 32 bits) your statement is not correct in general.

Comment: @TomBlodget You're missing the point. The size of the character object doesn't matter as long as it is big enough to represent all code unit. The point is that a single character object does not represent a sequence of code units.

Comment: I mean, for example, a UTF-8 code unit has a different size in bits than a UTF-16 code unit. A C++ implementation could choose `char` to be 8 bits or 16 bits but not both.